# Hibnernate insert or update datetime mysql always get 12:00:00 or 00:00:00

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

Im new in hibernate

I write a small application with hibernate and struts2

my problem is

when i update datetime my time will be 00:00:00 or 12:00:00 it not correct to what i choose like 04:50:10 or 18:20:11

I try many times but it till not work

In my form i have a field is string and then i convert it into date and then update it with hibernate

my convert code

```
public Date convertStringToDate(String str) {
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewsAdminAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return date;
    }

    public String convertDateToString(Date date) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String str = formatter.format(date);
        return str;
    }
```

my update code hibernate

```
//create session begin transaction

    String sqlNoThumb = "UPDATE News set title = :title, info = :info, publicdate = :publicdate, active = :active, titleviet = :titleviet where idnews = :idnews";

    Query query = session.createQuery(sqlNoThumb);
                    query.setString("title", news.getTitle());
                    query.setString("info", news.getInfo());
                    query.setDate("publicdate", news.getPublicdate());
                    query.setInteger("active", news.getActive());
                    query.setString("titleviet", news.getTitleviet());
                    query.setInteger("idnews", news.getIdnews());
                    result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Change your field from Date to Timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `java.sql.Timestamp`, not a `java.sql.Date`

[From the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

> *To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero*

Comment: thanks for support but it can't take hour minute and second @.@

Comment: i solved it with re-set update for my parameter from setDate to setTimeStamp!! thank you